# Custom auth name function - Laravel

Tags: laravel

I've multi-auth lumen app setup, one for business one for typical user. When I am authenticated as business I want to say:

auth()->business()->id

Rather than:

auth()->user()->id

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class

```php
<?php
namespace Illuminate\Support\Facades;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class CustomAuth extends Auth
{
    public static function company()
    {
        return $this->user()->business;
    //I'm not shure, but some like that
    }
}
```

and change in your `config/app.php`

```php
   'aliases' => [
        'App' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
        'Artisan' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
        //'Auth' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
        'Auth' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\CustomAuth::class,
```

you can read more in [laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/add-cutom-function-to-auth-facade).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the "web" guard then that uses the `SessionGuard` class as a guard. You can extend this as follows:

```
class MySessionGuard extends SessionGuard {
    

     private function isAuthenticatedAsBusiness($user) {
         // do your check here
        return false; // or true accordingly
 
   
    public function user() {
         $user = parent::user();
         return !$this->isAuthenticatedAsBusiness($user) ? $user : null;
    }

    public function business() {
         $user = parent::user();
         return $this->isAuthenticatedAsBusiness($user) ? $user : null;
    }
}
```

Then register this guard in your `AuthServiceProvider`:

```
public function boot() {
   Auth::extend("myweb", function ($app,$name, array $config) {
       $guard = new MySessionGuard(
            $name, 
            Auth::createUserProvider($config['provider']),
            $app["session.store"],
            $app["request"]
        );
        // This is copied from https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/43bea00fd27c76c01fd009e46725a54885f4d2a5/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.php#L121
        if (method_exists($guard, 'setDispatcher')) {
            $guard->setDispatcher($this->app['events']);
        }
        if (method_exists($guard, 'setCookieJar')) {
            $guard->setCookieJar($this->app['cookie']);
        }
        return $guard;
   });

   // ...
```

You can then update your `config/auth.php`

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'myweb',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        // ...
    ],
```

Your default guard should now be your custom one.

Comment: Using Lumen with JWT Token based authentication. No session.

Comment: You could probably use a similar approach to extend the default JWT token guard.